# Add background to a div based on a Node's Image Field 

Tags: theming

I had a request approach me and am blanking on a smooth way to implement this. We have on content type that on occasion will have a background image in a a div. The image will be a washed out background image behind content. The content authors want to add this page by page using an Image Field.

How would you implement this?

I'm assuming I can do this through our custom theme -- perhaps a theme_preprocess_page() or theme_process_page()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [BackgroundField](http://drupal.org/project/backgroundfield):

> BackgroundField started as an extension of the CCK ImageField that
>   allows a CSS selector and background attributes to be set for a
>   content-type. This is particularly helpful for allowing your node
>   authors to add images to a node that are integrated into the theme of
>   the site. With the inclusion of the Image field in Drupal 7,
>   BackgroundField was rewritten to extend that core functionality.

Comment: With this module added I removed a gunk load of code from my templete.php file. It looks so nice and clean again. Thank you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a module to do that: [Field Group Background Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_background_image)

The idea is creating a div wrapper (with [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group)), specifying the image field of your content type as the background image.