# Rotating image background in a div using Background Field

Tags: 7

I have successfully added background graphics using the module [BackgroundField](http://drupal.org/project/backgroundfield) module with the help of this [previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46243). We've had a feature creep in that we need to have a rotating image from a preset pool of images. Does anyone know of an module to facilitate this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the module does it automatically. I also asked for this as an interface enhancement on drupal.org. The developer [responded](http://drupal.org/node/1815606) saying that that feature already exists. All you have to do is set the field to unlimited. How freaking awesome is that?!

Answer (score 2):

It is not a Drupal Module but a very simply jQuery plugin to use.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

A snippet of me using it from my javascript:

```
function handle_header_carousel() {
    if ( jQuery('#header_carousel').get(0) == undefined ) {
        return;
    }
    jQuery('#header_carousel').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade', 
        speed:   300, 
        timeout: 3000, 
        next:   '#s3', 
        pause:   1 
    });
}
```

From my template page that houses the images:

```
<div id="header_carousel">
            <img src="/<?php echo drupal_get_path("theme", "tcth"); ?>/img/carousel_1.jpg" />
            <img src="/<?php echo drupal_get_path("theme", "tcth"); ?>/img/carousel_2.jpg" />
            <img src="/<?php echo drupal_get_path("theme", "tcth"); ?>/img/carousel_3.jpg" />
            <img src="/<?php echo drupal_get_path("theme", "tcth"); ?>/img/carousel_4.jpg" />
        </div>
```

Comment: I up-voted this as a great JS workaround but it turns out that this module had that built in already. Though, I may come back to this later. Thanks again.